# Module Has No default export | TypeScript RestAPI

Tags: node.js, typescript, rest

I am getting a red underline for the word `controller` when doing `import controller from '../controllers/test.controller';`

I have a rest api typescript application. Where I have the structure as shown... [project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKMhL.png)

I don't seem to understand why I am getting a red line under `controller` . Which says Module 'c:/users/home/desktop/RESTAPI_TS_NODEJS/source/controllers/test.controller has no default export. ts(1192)

Inside of my package.json I have..

```
{
  "name": "restapi_ts_nodejs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "source/server.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon source/server.ts",
    "build": "rm -rf build / && prettier --write source/ && tsc"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/axios": "^0.14.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.21",
    "@types/morgan": "^1.9.9",
    "axios": "^1.6.7",
    "express": "^4.18.3",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "nodemon": "^3.1.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "typescript": "^5.4.2"
  }
}
```

then inside of the tsconfig.json I have

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "outDir": "./build",
    "rootDir": "./source",
    "target": "es6",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true
  }
}
```

I have attempted doing `import { controller } from '../controllers/test.controller';` from reading online that this is a possible fix, but it didn't fix it. I then added in the tsconfig.json file the `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` to true as another possible solution and restarted vs code and nothing same issue.

This is what I have in `test.ts` which is located inside of the routes folder.

```
import express from 'express';
import controller from '../controllers/test.controller';
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/testRoute', controller.testFunction);

export default router;`
```

This is what I have in `test.controller.ts` which is inside of controllers folder

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from 'axios';

const testFunction = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    let result: AxiosResponse = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/com/todo/1');
    return res.send(result.data);
};
```

Comment: your controller does not export `testFunction`?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans no it doesn't, I am following this tutorial and I don't see that `testFunction` is being exported.. could that be the reason why its saying that? I did the similar thing but for `test.ts` inside of the routes folder shown in that website and I didnt get the same module error for import `test` https://roro88.medium.com/how-to-create-a-simple-rest-api-using-typescript-and-nodejs-324b80f0122d

Comment: Tutorials aren't perfect, so always use common sense: if you're importing something, that something needs to be exported somewhere. In this case, you're importing `testFunction`, so that needs to be exported by the file you're importing it from. And probably let the people who write the tutorial know that they forgot an `export` keyword.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to typescript, but okay this makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: I would hope they cover imports and exports before they throw this code at you: you need to know import/export before you can write any TS that's more than one file =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `test.controller.ts`File, there is no `export` clause.

But you import this file as controller in `test.ts`.

Please change your code like this.

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from 'axios';

const controller = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    const testFunction = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
        let result: AxiosResponse = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/com/todo/1');
        return res.send(result.data);
    };
}

export default controller
```

in your `test.controller.ts`

Comment: Thank you for the help! I went ahead and did as you said and added `export default` following the second line of code in your answer but now it has the keyword `const` underlined in red and it says "Expression expected. ts(1109). So I then removed those keywords and added `export default testFunction;` but then in test.ts file in `routes folder the `router.get('/testRoute', controller.testFunction);` `.testFunction` says testFunction does not exist on type Request<paramsDictionary>.....

Comment: Sorry , I am confused. I correct my answer. I think it will work correctly.